# Can I swap parts between Apple devices? will Apple notice?

Tags: iphone

Can I (legally) replace an iPhone 6s screen with another's screen (same model)?

Can I (legally) replace a macbook screen with another's screen (same model)?

Would Apple notice?

I know this sounds a bit low, it's just out of curiosity, it's good for a technician to know this I guess.

Comment: I don't expect they notice, as long you really get original parts.

Comment: Nobody but Apple can answer this question.  Anything you get from here will only be a guess.

Comment: Let's fix your first question. This is worse since legal isn't what we do here. If you are asking what is the end user license - that's marginally on topic. legal depends on your jurisdiction and a lawyer to explain the conflicting laws. The best we try to do on Ask Different is point people to end user language so you can consult with your lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

I did this on an iPhone 6 for a friend. The glass was cracked and the other iPhone was water damage but screen was working fine. Moved of course the home button over. I know Apple is hardening down on non-original parts so I was surprised when the fixed phone had a warranty issue and Apple replaced the device. So they either did not check the screen carefully enough or it was ok. Not to say this would work again but they would nowadays be very quick to hit down on a non-original screen. A couple of years ago I could fix an iPhone 5 with a 3rd party screen and get the iPhone replaced on a warranty issue (bad headphone). Would probably never pass today.

As for the screen, there are no non-original screen assemblies out there so that should not be a problem. That is for Retina models. Not sure if they would notice if you replaced the LCD-only on an older MacBook.